# Creating New Contact Google People API

Tags: python, google-people-api, google-python-api

I was following the guide:
https://developers.google.com/people/v1/write-people

My Code:

```
def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google People API
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('people', 'v1', http=http,
        discoveryServiceUrl='https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest')

    contact2 = service.people().createContact(
        body={"names": [{"givenName": "John", "familyName": "Doe"}]}).execute()

    contact2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When i run, My Error:

```
~/quickstart.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/quickstart.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "~/quickstart.py", line 66, in main
    contact2()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am getting this error. How do I effectively create a new contact?

Comment: Please provides the full traceback. That error can happen everywhere in the code

Comment: I think thats the full traceback..

Comment: contact2 is a dictionary, not a function, so you cannot call it. I don't know the API, but I bet that the ``execute()`` method returns a dictionary with the response to your request.

Comment: My intention was to create a contact. It did create and save if i call contact2.execute().. So the problem is now solved. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: This api has been deprecated by google. See ['Link to announcement']( https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/announcement)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:
`contact2()`
`service.people().createContact` returns dictionary as response and you are trying to call it.

dictionary object is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, although I do not understand why. I was able to save contact using:

```
contact2 = service.people().createContact(
        body={"names": [{"givenName": "John", "familyName": "Doe"}]})

contact2.execute()
```